# How to target tablets only with your Android app?

Tags: android, google-play, android-manifest

I apologize in advance if it's a dumb question, but what's the current approach to target tablets only?

I have an older app that is only suitable for tablets. I made some updates to it, so I want to deploy it to Google Play Store.

The problem is that when I look at the list of supported devices, many popular newer tablets like Samsung Galaxy Tab S8 (various models), Xiaomi Pad 5, and such are marked as unsupported as they don't seem to fall into any category specified in the manifest.

I'm using the following  setting in my manifest:

```
<supports-screens 
    android:anyDensity="true" 
    android:largeScreens="true" 
    android:normalScreens="false" 
    android:resizeable="true" 
    android:smallScreens="false" 
    android:xlargeScreens="true" 
    android:requiresSmallestWidthDp="600" />
```

I also used  tags before to target special densities (like 213 for Asus Nexus 7), but I really don't want to specify all densities manually (like 340 or 360 for S8 or Pad 5). Is there a better way to handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a reliable way to do it unless you list the devices manually. I had a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72323442/enable-installing-only-on-small-and-normal-devices)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback and link. I expected there would be a solution by now. iOS has that solved pretty cleanly.
So basically you checked the densities on Google Play Console and added all the common densities into the compatible-screen tag?

Comment: I guess that for iOS is simpler because there aren't as many devices as on Android but I thought it was going to be easier too.

Comment: How did you add a device like the Xiaomi Pad 5, which doesn't fit in any of those recommended densities (280, 360, 420, 480, 560)? As far as I remember, it's density is 340. You just manually added the device?

Comment: That's the only solution I found and it isn't nice